# BigQuery - Granting Read Permission, but not Dataset Creation Privileges

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to grant users the ability to view and query tables in a specific dataset (and only that dataset), without granting them the ability to also create new datasets within the overall project?

I'm trying to give access to a third party to integrate with a very specific subset of our data.

The documentation I've been reading is here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.user

Answer (score 0):

You can share the specific dataset with your 3rd parties by. Using the web UI:

```
Dataset -> Share Dataset -> Email/user -> "Can View"
```

Add the user as viewer. They can now see and query (using their own Google account) the tables in your dataset, but not create anything in your project.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me. For some reason, the 3rd party needs to create their own BQ project before being able to access the dataset I want to share. If the 3rd party is an organization that uses Google Apps, and the individual does not have Project Creator status on their account, they won't be able to access my dataset. The solution I've found is to add them individually to my project, but this gives them permissions way beyond what I'm comfortable with.

Comment: Yes, they need their own Google billing project because they will running queries for which they have to pay for.

Answer (score 0):

They should have the role bigquery.jobUser.

This gives them the permission to query but not the ability to create datasets.

This role is applied at the org and dataset level.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.jobUser